# Script to automate pushing to remote Github repo, won't work with crontab?

Tags: git, shell, github, cron, git-push

I'm trying to make a simple shell script that pushes to Github my current workspace and automatically launch that script every 12 hours with `cron`.

Here's what I got:

---

*`shell` script:*

```
#!/bin/sh

git -C ~/backups/tools pull
git -C ~/backups/tools add .
git -C ~/backups/tools commit -m 'Automatic Backup of Latest Changes'
git -C ~/backups/tools push origin master
```

---

*`crontab` file:*

```
0 */12 * * * sh ~/scripts/backup-tools.sh
```

---

`log` file: (I also logged the output)

```
  [master xxxxxx] Automatic Backup of Latest Changes
   1 file changed, 70 insertions(+), 43 deletions(-)
```

---

`git` log:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1 (HEAD -> master)
Author: user <address@mail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 27 12:00:00 2020 -0700

    Automatic Backup of Latest Changes

commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2
Author: user <address@mail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 27 00:00:01 2020 -0700

    Automatic Backup of Latest Changes

commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: user <address@mail.com>
Date:   Sun Jul 26 10:02:53 2020 -0700

    Latest Change
```

---

Running the script manually works, and pushes everything remotely. Now leaving the script to be run by `crontabs` also works, i.e the script executes, the only  problem being, which you can notice from the `git` log, that the `origin master` branch has not moved and nothing has been uploaded remotely since I last pushed it myself.

Does anyone know what the problem is ? And what's the fix ?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you push to origin? Please add the output from `git remote -v`. Have you tried running the script from the command line and does it work? Does the user running the script in the cronjob have the same environment as your user?

Comment: @Ente, `git -C ~/backups/tools push origin master`, this is how I push to origin, it's a private repository. I have tried running the script from the command line and it works perfectly. I would assume that the cronjob has the same environment, it acts on behalf of my user as far as I've understood it; `~/backups/tools` places the command call in the `.git` directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work is because the `cron` job was launching a script on a new terminal instance that didn't source my `.zshrc` and `.bashrc` which contained macros and important information for the script. So I added this to the script:

```
if [ -z ${ZSH+x} ]; then        # <--- if .zshrc wasn't sourced yet
  source ~/.zshrc               # <--- source it
fi
```

...and it worked great.